# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null in typescript

```
export class UserForm {
  constructor(public parent: Element) {}

  template(): string {
    return `
        <div>
        <h1> User Form</h1>
        <input/>
        <div>
        `;

  }

  render(): void {
    const templateElement = document.createElement('template');
    templateElement.innerHTML = this.template();
    console.log(this.parent);
    this.parent.append(templateElement.content);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well? `this.parent` is null, that's why you're getting the error message.

Comment: Can you show a use case?

Comment: @Mike S : Yeah I've seen that, Even though i've assigned interface Element to the parent and trying to append, it's showing the null. I'm a beginner to the TypeScript and so I can't handle this.

Comment: You need to search your code for everything that assigns `Element`.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaChaitanya, did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign an initial value like:

```
constructor(public parent: Element) {
  this.parent =[];
}
```

Comment: The parent should be an `Element` object, not an array.