# How to resolve this parent: Element returning null?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I saw an old post that was never resolved and I am invested in it now.

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673611/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-append-of-null-in-typescript)

I tried reproducing it and I am also getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

```
export class UserForm {
  constructor(public parent: Element) {}

  template(): string {
    return `
        <div>
        <h1> User Form</h1>
        <input/>
        <div>
        `;

  }

  render(): void {
    const templateElement = document.createElement('template');
    templateElement.innerHTML = this.template();
    console.log(this.parent);
    this.parent.append(templateElement.content);
  }
}
```

`this.parent` console logs `null` for me as well. I thought perhaps it was because the DOM was not loading in time, but I tried this:

```
export class UserForm {
  // parent: Element;

  // constructor(parent: Element) {
  //   this.parent = parent;
  // }
  constructor(public parent: Element) {}

  template(): string {
    return `<div>
      <h1>User Form</h1>
      <input />
    </div>`;
  }

  render(): void {
    const templateElement = document.createElement("template");
    templateElement.innerHTML = this.template();
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
      console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    });
    console.log(this.parent);
    this.parent.append(templateElement.content);
  }
}
```

And I got the console log of `DOM fully loaded and parsed` but `this.parent` is still `null`. If you do command + click for `Element` you get that `Element is the most general base class from which all objects in a Document inherit.`

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

So far, I believe this has something to do with the fact that you do not always find an `Element` in TypeScript, so you would get `null` instead, but if this is the case, how do we resolve that?

Comment: Have you attempted debugging the constructor and putting `console.log(parent);` in the constructor function to make sure you're passing through the correct object being assigned as parent?

Another thing that might help is binding the render method to the class so in the constructor method add this to the bottom:
`this.render = this.render.bind(this);`

Comment: @MatthewDAuld, I just tried what you suggested and I am getting `null` for `console.log(parent)`.

Comment: that means where ever the class constructor is for the new UserForm(parent) the parent is null so it's not the class that's the issue. You're gonna have to follow the code back to where the original parent is to make sure it's not null.

Comment: @MatthewDAuld, I don't initialize that `parent` anywhere else. It all starts with the `UserForm` class. My understanding of the original post was that they needed to ensure that their string that contains some amount of HTML would be inserted into the DOM. `parent` is a reference to some HTML element that exists inside the DOM. I am open to alternatives, maybe it just doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that the key to solving this is the not null assertion operator or what in the world of English grammar we know as the exclamation point.

Basically, you tell TypeScript to relax and stop yelling at you because you know what you are doing. Root constant will definitely reference `Element`. Otherwise, if the operator were to be omitted, root could refer to `Element` or `null`, if the element could not be found.

```
export class UserForm {
  constructor(public parent: Element) {}

  template(): string {
    return `<div>
      <h1>User Form</h1>
      <input />
    </div>`;
  }

  render(): void {
    const templateElement = document.createElement("template");
    templateElement.innerHTML = this.template();
    console.log(this.parent);

    this.parent.append(templateElement.content);
  }
}
```

Below would be the `index.ts` file:

```
import { UserForm } from "./views/UserForm";

const root: Element = document.getElementById("root")!;

const userForm = new UserForm(root);

userForm.render();
```

Below is the `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./src/index.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas I came up with that might help fix this.

A: Bind the render method to the class.
B: Add an if statement to prevent the error from happening.

```
export class UserForm {
  constructor(public parent: Element) {
    console.log(parent);
    // Maybe binding the render method here might help.
    this.render = this.render.bind(this);
  }

  template(): string {
    return `<div>
      <h1>User Form</h1>
      <input />
    </div>`;
  }

  render(): void {
    const templateElement = document.createElement("template");
    templateElement.innerHTML = this.template();
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
      console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    });
    console.log(this.parent);
    // Add a clause to prevent the error
    if(this.parent){
      this.parent.append(templateElement.content);
    }
  }
}
```

These are just some ideas.